# How to disable shordcode in a category description backend, in admin area?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have enabled shortcodes in pretty much everywhere by adding this line:

```
add_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Unfortunately it now shows in admin area, in the category tab, in the description of a category where the shortcode is present. I only want it to be executed on an actual page, I don't need to preview it in the admin area.

Is there a way of disabling it being executed in the admin area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin

Is this what you're seeking?

```
if( is_admin() == false )
{
  add_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' );
}
```

Comment: Well... This was quick, considering I spent at least an hour trying to figure out different phrases to put in google search and I couldn't find anything. Thanks for this, I wasn't aware of "is_admin()" function at all but then I don't often work with Wordpress. Great stuff, thanks again!

Comment: Yeah the terminology can be a bit confusing some times, but that's mostly due to legacy reasons.